# Match hexadecimal notated bytes regex

Tags: regex, haxe

I am trying to match and group hexadecimal bytes (i.e. 2 digit hex values) with the regular expression -> `~/([0-9a-f]{2}/`.

I want to store these grouped matches without altering the original string `sbytes`.

What do I need to do to achieve this? Thanks.

```
var sbytes: String = "cafebabe";
var hexr = ~/([0-9a-f]{2})/; // Match a hexadecimal notated byte.
hexr.match(sbytes);
trace(hexr.matched(1));

// I want to match each byte (ca, fe, ba, be) into a match group
// (E.g. ca = hexr.matched(1), fe = hexr.matched(2), et cetera).
// How do I do this?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry to say that, but haxe EReg class misses some methods for frequent usecases. However, it's still achievable. Try this:

```
class Test {
  static function main() {
    var sbytes: String = "cafebabe";

    var hexbyteRe = ~/[0-9a-f]{2}/;

    var pos = 0;
    while(hexbyteRe.matchSub(sbytes, pos)){
      trace(hexbyteRe.matched(0));
      var mp = hexbyteRe.matchedPos();
      pos = mp.pos + mp.len;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `matchSub()` was what I'm missing. I also couldn't believe that there isn't something like this in haxe. I expected something like `matchAll()` which would return the result of a matching group as an array (multiple results in that group, like `preg_match_all()` in PHP)...

Comment: I believe it's due to facts regexps are used so rarely overall and EReg class was established pretty early in haxe life. Also, the differences in underlying platform implementations complicate it all. I had my own regexp class for haxe some time ago, which had it all, guess I should update it and try to add to std.

Comment: Yes you should do that. Btw, I really loved to code flash in that good old times :). I must say this was my first look on Haxe. I like it. Seems you have more practice. May I ask for what kind of work you are using it?

Comment: Well, I'm working with haxe for many years and used it for all kind of things. Flash graphics and physics engines for games, php websites, optical character recognition in cpp, various tools, compilers and decompilers for various platforms. My current focus is performant webservers for node.js platform and single-page web applications for html+js.

Answer (score 2):

I would use four separate capturing groups:

```
class Test {

    static function main() {
        var sbytes: String = "cafebabe";
        // Match 4 hexadecimal notated bytes. Match each of them in a 
        // separate capturing group.
        var hexr = ~/([0-9a-f]{2})([0-9a-f]{2})([0-9a-f]{2})([0-9a-f]{2})/;
        hexr.match(sbytes);

        trace(hexr.matched(1));
        trace(hexr.matched(2));
        trace(hexr.matched(3));
        trace(hexr.matched(4));
    }
}
```

You can try the code here: http://try.haxe.org/#CA3d8

Comment: Thanks. I guess if I wanted to test a longer string, I could just get the length of it and construct a regex dynamically which is half the length.

Comment: I'm not a Haxe expert but after digging trough the related documentation, I would say "yes".

Comment: Sorry, but no, this way is totally unacceptable in any language. The maximum length of regexp string is pretty limited. The number of matchgroups is even more limited for most regexp engines. Inner state of compiled regexp takes a lot of memory. Compilation of regexp itself takes A LOT of time. After all, I didn't test it, but I predict this way of parsing will be thousands times slower than any sane way.

Comment: @stroncium Yes, a large number of capturing groups is unfeasible for many reasons. You named most of them, let me add that dynamic code generation isn't a good practice too. You showed a good alternative in your answer. However, for this example - a mac address - I still think simply using four capturing groups is the best way..